# Why are files copied from Asar readonly?

Tags: javascript, node.js, electron

I have an electron app, and when I build it for distribution, the actual app code and build folder are on app.asar file. During the app runtime, I have to copy certain files from the app.asar onto the user's computer, wherever the user chooses, and modify  with the code.

The problem is that whenever the file is copied, it becomes readonly, and thus I can not write to it. Any way to handle this?

Answer (score 2):

I'm running into this issue as well, I think the issue is that only some of the `fs` methods are ported over to work well with `asar`. According to the [docs](https://electronjs.org/docs/tutorial/application-packaging),

> With special patches in Electron, Node APIs like `fs.readFile` and `require` treat `asar` archives as virtual directories, and the files in it as normal files in the filesystem.

Therefore, I think the solution is to manually copy the content of files from `asar` using `fs.readFile` and then to dump that into the file you want. I will try this today and hopefully post an update with some code.

Comment: This is what I ended up doing as well, copying the contents only.